# C11 and C++11 problems in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, c, c++11, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I upgrade my Sublime Text 3 for C/C++ but I have to write code in modern versions like C11 and C++11.

When I try C11 code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    puts("C99 Version:");

    for( int i = 0; argv[i]; i++ ) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Sublime gives an errors:

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\c99.c:7:2: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
  for( int i = 0; argv[i]; i++ ) {
  ^
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\c99.c:7:2: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
```

Can You explain me how to use -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 options?

==================================================================================

The same thing with C++11. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    stringstream version;
    version << "GCC version: "
            << __GNUC__ << "." << __GNUC_MINOR__ << "." << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__
            << "\nVersion string: " << __VERSION__;

    cout << version.str() << endl;

    vector<string> v = { "one", "two", "three" }; // C++11 feature - initializer list

    for( string s : v ) {   // C++11 feature - range-based for loop
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and a list of errors:

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\main.cpp:17:45: error: in C++98 'v' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
  vector<string> v = { "one", "two", "three" }; // C++11 feature - initializer list
                                             ^
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\main.cpp:17:45: error: could not convert '{"one", "two", "three"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >'
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\CPPproject\main.cpp:19:18: error: range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
  for( string s : v ) { // C++11 feature - range-based for loop
                  ^
```

Help me solve these problems please!

And another one question: When I run the code - .exe file appears in the same folder with source code and I have to open it. Are there any possibilities to see the output inside Sublime Text when I click "ctrl+b" ???

Thank's !!!

Comment: Sublime Text doesn't have a compiler or syntax-checker by itself, it must be in a module you have installed. Check the configuration file for that module.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Misleading. This is an issue that can easily be fixed without installing anything. Sublime Text does have build systems (i.e. commands to run on a file or project). Luchnik just has to configure them.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) on ST3 build systems. Create yourself a new one for each C and C++ that include the appropriate `-std` flag.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the comments, it's your build system that you need to alter. I ST3 it's a bit trickier to modify the default packages. There are plugins to do this, but I have yet to use them. Here is a plugin free way.

First, you will need a new `.sublime-build`. I think this one should work.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "${file}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Build without C++11",
            "cmd": ["g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you will need to navigate to where default packages for ST3 are stored. It seems you are using Windows. The location of the `.sublime-package`s is probably something like C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages.

Once inside this folder, you should see a bunch of `.sublime-package` files with the names of all the languages that have builtin support. Choose the `C++.sublime-package` and make a copy of it to some other directory. Then, rename it to `C++.zip` and extract it. Remove the `C++.sublime-build` file and replace it with a file named the same way containing the above code. Re-zip the file and rename it back to `C++.sublime-package` and place it back into the folder you got it from.

Now:

- When you press ctrl+b, ST3 will automatically build using the C++11 flag for gcc.
- If you want to run your program (I think that's what you mean by "see the output inside Sublime Text") press ctrl+shift+b after the program has been compiled.
- If you want to build using gcc but *without* the C++11 flags, press ctrl+shift+p and type in "Build: Build without C++11" and select the option that pops up.

Comment: You do not have to modify the '.sublime-package' file. Instead you can place the new 'C++.sublime-build' file in your user package folder in a subfolder also called 'C++'. In my case the file is in this position '....\SublimeText\Data\Packages\User\C++\C++.sublime-build'.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a typo in the last item of the first command line array (`"${file}""`).

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Yeah, looks like a misplaced quotation mark. Fixed.

Comment: @Alec : Last line missing a double quotation mark. Once fixed it works perfectly!

Comment: @sookie Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you do this, you might encounter an error, say a syntax error, or some other kind of error to avoid all that use the standard C++ configuration, just add the keyword -std=c++11 after g++ in shell_cmd
Example

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Build without C++11",
            "cmd": ["g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

That does it. C++98 is the same config without -std=c+11 options.

For more info on how to deal with these kinds of file please head over to the [sublime documentation about build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alec's solution worked well for me, but the run variant called "Run" will not build with C++11, so I added one more run option, called "Run with C++11":

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "${file}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        },
    {
            "name": "Run with C++11",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -std=c++11 -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Build without C++11",
            "cmd": ["g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 3 makes harder to modify the default settings; to change them, you can use the package "PackageResourceViewer". Install this package (PackageControl is recommended), then hit Ctrl+shift+P and execute the commands:

PackageResourceViewer: OpenResource -> C++ -> C++ Single File.sublime-build

Add the option "-std=C++11" after every "g++ " command you find. Save and close the file. You should be able to compile now.

(The file should look like the one below after the changes)

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```